# Como obter o serial number ou ID de um pendrive no sistema MS-DOS?

Tags: c, c++, assembly, ms-dos

Já tentei usar algumas ferramentas para obter informações de hardware no DOS, mas não tinham o código fonte para uso livre. Preciso de uma solução de código que me retorne o serial number ou ID no ambiente MS-DOS.

Comment: Estou usando o MS-DOS 7.10  e o DJGPP como compilador.

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer `dir` e apanhar o output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// O prefixo do `dir` que identifica o serial number
#define SNPREFIX " Volume Serial Number is "
// MUDAR AQUI ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

int main(void) {
    char line[512];
    FILE *process;
    process = popen("cmd /c dir c:", "r");
    // MUDAR AQUI --------------^
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, process)) {
        line[strlen(line) - 1] = 0; // clear ENTER
        if (strncmp(line, SNPREFIX, strlen(SNPREFIX)) == 0) {
            printf("==> %s <==\n", line + strlen(SNPREFIX));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output na minha máquina (no teu caso tens de mudar o "c:" para a letra que está associada à pen drive)

```
==> 8662-7ACB <==
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi o que você procura é isto:

```
wmic diskdrive get PNPDeviceID
```

Ou:

```
wmic diskdrive get SerialNumber
```

Fonte: https://superuser.com/questions/600394/get-usb-key-manufacturer-serial-number

Comment: WMIC veio com o windows 2000 se não me engano. DOS 7.1 é da época do 95, no máximo 98.